# multiply data from database to value from textbox

Tags: php, mysql

i have 1 table named tbl_sales. the ff data in tbl_sales are

> id | total |
>
> 1  | 100   |

my question is this. i want to update "total" by multiplying it to whatever values in textbox.
this is my code so far to display textbox. i echo it so that everytime i add order it will appear on every table row

```
echo '<td>'.$vats_tot.'</td>';  //- the value display in this row is from database.
echo 'input type = "text" name = "ds"/>;
```

my problem is this. i want to multiply this the value from this textbox to "$vats_tot" which is from database value. can it be possible to multiply this?

Comment: Do you actually want to update the value in the table?

Comment: yes i want to update so that it will only change the "total" value.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$txt_val = $_POST['ds'];
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_sales SET total = total * $txt_val";
```

Answer (score 0):

sql query for your problem

```
$textbox_value=$_post['textbox_id'];//To get TextBox Value

update **[table_name]** set total=(total*$textbox_value) where id=1;//To update the data into the table
```